# Surface is destroyed after the activity has been recreated

Tags: java, android, android-activity, surfaceview, android-context

Alright I am creating a android game where the player walks moves around a grid style map. When the `mainActivity` is initially created the `surfaceCreated` method is called, then the `surfaceChanged` method is called and then it waits for user input. When the player hits the side of a screen the `mainActivity` is started again by `getContext().startActivity(intent);` this recreates the `mainActivity` and loads the new map in. Which re-creates the surface. The `surfaceCreated` method, then `surfaceChanged` method, then `surfaceDestroyed` method are called right after each other. Disabling the surfaceView stopping the user from being able to control the object on the screen.

How can I make it so the the `surfaceDestroyed` method is not called when the activity is re-created?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting. Please look through the [help center on posting code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).  A more concert code example would improve your post (e.g., a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, you can use backticks to format inline code.

Answer (score 1):

Recreating an Activity is a fairly heavyweight operation.  All of the old UI is torn down to free up resources for the new Activity.

The Surface component of a SurfaceView is handled somewhat asynchronously, which is why the created/destroyed events are reported through callbacks.  Add log messages to each callback that include the value of the SurfaceHolder argument so can see which instance of the Surface is being created or destroyed -- I suspect you're getting the "destroyed" for the old surface after the "created" for the new surface, and that's messing you up.

What you probably want to do is leave the Activity running and just update your state.  That will be much more efficient.